# How to build a conditional Procedure to operate (if-then-insert-else-update) on multiple tables using MySQL in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-trigger

I use MySQL to manage a database.
I have 2 tables named IDENTITY and OPTIONS in a database named WIFI.
IDENTITY contains 2 fields: USERNAME and PASSWORD.
OPTIONS contains 3 fields: USERNAME, WIFI_SSID and WIFI_PASSWORD.
And there is a procedure accepting these variables as argument:
arg01_USERNAME
arg02_PASSWORD
arg03_WIFI_SSID
arg04_WIFI_PASSWORD
I want to build a procedure in phpMyAdmin to do this operation:

This procedure should check if the arg01_USERNAME and arg02_PASSWORD match the data in IDENTITY. If data not found, then do nothing. Else search for arg01_USERNAME in table OPTIONS and update WIFI_SSID and WIFI_PASSWORD with arg03_WIFI_SSID and arg04_WIFI_PASSWORD. If arg01_USERNAME not found in OPTIONS, then insert a new record into OPTIONS.

Here is the SQL query to define procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`WIFI`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `INSERT`(IN `arg01_USERNAME` INT(20) UNSIGNED, IN `arg02_PASSWORD` VARCHAR(32), IN `arg03_WIFI_SSID` VARCHAR(32) CHARSET utf8, IN `arg04_WIFI_PASSWORD` VARCHAR(32) CHARSET utf8)
    NO SQL
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM `WIFI`.`IDENTITY` 
    WHERE `USERNAME` = arg01_USERNAME AND `PASSWORD` = arg02_PASSWORD)
THEN
    INSERT INTO `WIFI`.`OPTIONS` (
        `USERNAME`,
        `WIFI_SSID`,
        `WIFI_PASSWORD`
    ) VALUES (
        arg01_USERNAME,
        arg03_WIFI_SSID,
        arg04_WIFI_PASSWORD
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        `WIFI_SSID` = arg03_WIFI_SSID,
        `WIFI_PASSWORD` = arg04_WIFI_PASSWORD
END IF;
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Could you please point me out what is wrong with this code?
When I try to define the procedure using this code, phpMyAdmin tells me there is a syntax error near "END IF" part of the code(error 1064).
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: When I try to define the procedure using this code, phpMyAdmin tells me there is a syntax error. Error 1064.
When I remove condition part (Just use INSERT), syntax error goes away.

Comment: Is there a more detailed error message than just a syntax error? For instance, does it tell you what character or line the syntax error failed on?

Comment: @MehdiMaazi please update your question to add complete code that you run on PHPMyAdmin to create the Stored procedure, and also the error messsage you get.

Comment: Sorry Venantius and Madhur Bhaiya. It is a long error message that goes beyond my display. It tells me this:
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 36.
I updated the question. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Stored procedures are using `create procedure` statement. Please use proper syntax to create

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya
I posted my query to build the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to redefined Delimiter to something else, for eg: `$$`, so that parser does not trigger query execution when it sees `;`
- At the end, redefine the Delimiter back to `;`.

Try:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`WIFI`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `INSERT`(IN `arg01_USERNAME` INT(20) UNSIGNED, IN `arg02_PASSWORD` VARCHAR(32), IN `arg03_WIFI_SSID` VARCHAR(32) CHARSET utf8, IN `arg04_WIFI_PASSWORD` VARCHAR(32) CHARSET utf8)
    NO SQL
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM `WIFI`.`IDENTITY` 
    WHERE `USERNAME` = arg01_USERNAME AND `PASSWORD` = arg02_PASSWORD)
THEN
    INSERT INTO `WIFI`.`OPTIONS` (
        `USERNAME`,
        `WIFI_SSID`,
        `WIFI_PASSWORD`
    ) VALUES (
        arg01_USERNAME,
        arg03_WIFI_SSID,
        arg04_WIFI_PASSWORD
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        `WIFI_SSID` = arg03_WIFI_SSID,
        `WIFI_PASSWORD` = arg04_WIFI_PASSWORD;
END IF $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks but same error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 38

Comment: @MehdiMaazi check the updated answer now. a semicolon was missing. typo